# Call Dotnet Core Aspnet Rest with Put and curl

Tags: rest, curl, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

How do I write a [curl](https://curl.haxx.se) statement to `PUT` an Dotnet core aspnet 1.1 rest method?

I can get it to recognise my integer id but not my string payload.

---

The method is:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult Put(int id, string name){...
```

copied from [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api#implement-the-other-crud-operations).

When I curl with:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -X PUT \
    --data '{"Name":"Tva"}' \
    localhost:5000/api/todo/2
```

it does recognise the id 2 in the URL but not the `Name` parameter. Instead the method receives it as null.
The web server spits out `Executing action method WebApplication.Controllers.TodoController.Put (MyWs) with arguments (2, ) - ModelState is Invalid`

I also tried setting a `[FromBody]` tag

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody] string name){...
```

and call it like so:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;" \
    -X PUT \
    -F "name=Tva" \
    localhost:5000/api/todo/2/
```

but then I got a 415.

(I do have permutated the calls and callees above but haven't found the right combination. Something is missing.)

---

**Small edit:**
´dotnet new´ is [updated with RC4](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/02/07/announcing-net-core-tools-updates-in-vs-2017-rc/) to also create a web api project. I have not investigated yet if i have written the callee the same way as Microsoft supposes I should.
My SO question stands but may be less relevant in the future. I will get back on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try curl with:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -X PUT \
    --data '"Tva"' \
    localhost:5000/api/todo/2
```

Or try with a wrapper model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody] MyModel model){...
```

and curl with:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -X PUT \
    --data '{"name": "Tva"}' \
    localhost:5000/api/todo/2
```